# svn clear projects with all revisions

Tags: linux, svn

is there a commend to delete project from svn with all its revisions(total cleanup) ?

cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is in the [Subversion FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal):

> There are special cases where you
>   might want to destroy all evidence of
>   a file or commit. (Perhaps somebody
>   accidentally committed a confidential
>   document.) This isn't so easy, because
>   Subversion is deliberately designed to
>   never lose information. Revisions are
>   immutable trees which build upon one
>   another. Removing a revision from
>   history would cause a domino effect,
>   creating chaos in all subsequent
>   revisions and possibly invalidating
>   all working copies.
>
> The project has plans, however, to
>   someday implement an svnadmin
>   obliterate command which would
>   accomplish the task of permanently
>   deleting information. (See issue 516.)
>
> In the meantime, your only recourse is
>   to svnadmin dump your repository, then
>   pipe the dumpfile through
>   svndumpfilter (excluding the bad path)
>   into an svnadmin load command. See
>   chapter 5 of the Subversion book for
>   details about this.

Comment: thanks for that, here is a good article about it: http://blog.projectnibble.org/2008/03/01/subversion-obliterate-the-forgotten-feature/ cheers

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe there is.

If you really need to remove files completely from SVN history, I think the only way to do it would be to do something like dumping the repository, filtering out the files you don't want with [svndumpfilter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svndumpfilter), and then recreate the repository from the dump.

Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have a project which I would like to completly remove from my repo.

Answer (score 0):

`rm -rf` on the repository usually works fine.

Comment: I was living under the impression that svn keeps its database somewhere in the server repository, so nuking the repository will get rid of it as well. I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

this is how to do this on Linux:

```
/>svnadmin dump /path/to/repos > proj.dump
/>cat proj.dump | svndumpfilter exclude somefolder > cleanproj.dump
/>service svn stop
/>BACKUP /path/to/repos/conf /path/to/repos/hooks (all custom configuration for this repository)
/>DELETE /path/to/repos
/>svnadmin create /path/to/repos
/>RESTORE /path/to/repos/conf /path/to/repos/hooks
/>svnadmin load /path/to/repos < cleanproj.dump
/>service svn start
```

done

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are talking about multiple projects under the same repository:

```
myrepo/
      project1/
      project2/
```

If you simply want a project to 'disappear' without screwing with the repository history, you can simply hide this path if you are using an authentication mechanism that utilizes authz.  In other words, you are *not* using 'svn+ssh' to access the repository.

Let's say I already have a group in my authz called 'everyone'.  The in my authz I will set something  like:

```
[/project1]:
    @everyone =
```